# subtract data from two columns and result into one column.`

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data like below

```
id   year   marks    id    year    marks 
1    2017   80       1     2018    100  
2    2017   60       2     2018    70 
3    2017   500      3     2018    600
```

My result should be values as **20, 10, 100** in **Difference column**.
All this data should be in a single row.

Comment: What is the query which generated this data, and why are these two columns both called `marks`?

Comment: I don't have the query, its just a sample of my requirement. I want to see the data just like that. you can imagine the column names to be old_year, new_year, old_marks and new marks.

Comment: pls show us the result that you want. Which columns to display and their values.

Comment: My data has only id, year and marks columns. After we construct the query it should be all the columns with Diff column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you just want to take a difference of the two marks columns:

```
SELECT
    t1.id, t1.year, t1.marks AS marks_2017, t2.id, t2.year, t2.marks AS marks_2018,
    t2.marks - t1.marks AS diff
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.year = 2017 AND t2.year = 2018;
```

Comment: i want to calculate only for 2018 marks minus 2017 marks, where are you doing that?

Comment: @newbie I updated my answer.  Perhaps this is what you want.

Comment: This is what im exactly looking for, Thanks a lot for your help. I was trying to use subquery or some other approach.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow, I think you want:

```
select id, sum(case when year = 2018 then marks else - marks end) as diff
from t
where year in (2017, 2018)
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, year, marks, id, year, new_marks, new_marks - marks AS diff
FROM yourTable where year = '2018'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
t1.*, t2.year, t2.marks, t2.marks - t1.marks as diff
from
test t1
inner join
test t2
on t1.id = t2.id and t1.year = 2017 and t2.year = 2018
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da1e20/1)